# ASP.NET web optimization framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-optimization

I am bundling and minifying my javascript files as shown below

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CommunityMaintenance")
                  .Include(
                  "~/Scripts/Common.js",
                  "~/Scripts/AjaxEnhancers.js",
                  "~/Scripts/CommunityMaintenance.js",
                  "~/Scripts/TAR.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js"
                  ));


                ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
                   "CommunityMaintenance",
                   new ScriptResourceDefinition
                   {
                       Path = "~/bundles/CommunityMaintenance"
                   });
```

However, when I need to turn it off using

```
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

This does not work. I have registered my bundles in the Application_Start method in Global.asax and am disabling optimization in the very next line. I have even set the debug to true but it makes no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe is keeps some cache, try also to change and one of the js files to force him to update it.

Comment: That was the first thing I did, it does not unfortunately.